# How to merge individual tables into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two separate tables which maintains User and Policy details.
User can have only one Policy -> 1:1

My requirement is to merge these two tables into one , User_Policy
If User has 5 columns and Policy has 3 Columns then User_Policy has 8 columns.

User and Policy details will be imported into User and Policy table via ETL (some import job)
the import job contains both User and Policy details as csv and User definitely has one policy (no orphan records)

I want to insert/update User_Policy whenever there is an insert/update in User/Policy tables and vice-versa. Means, when there is an insert/update in User_Policy table, the data has to be inserted/updated in respective individual tables.

My plan is to write a trigger on User, Policy, User_Policy tables - the trigger inserts/updates the records in the respective table. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, the User insert triggers insert into User_Policy insert and the insert trigger in User_Policy again triggered -going infinite - Am not sure how to avoid this?

So, I have created a job table, which holds the status, record_id - the status tells whether it has updated from individual table or merged table -

Note: all tables have a column called externalid, which is unique across all the tables.

Please suggest which one is better. Any new design/idea would also be helpful.

Suresh

Comment: You want a VIEW and an INSTEAD OF trigger. Please provide more details for better answers.

Comment: I don't want a VIEW - User_Policy will be used as the main table going forward - that's why I want to merge and User and Policy into a single table. ETL can only be configured to insert/update individual tables (this cannot be changed)

Comment: You can use [pg_trigger_depth ()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) to detect a triggerg recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the design needs to be revisited.

You can have either of the situations:

1. Application does DML on USER_POLICY table.
2. Application does DML on USER as well as POLICY tables.

Application should **NOT** be doing DML on  USER & POLICY as well as on USER_POLICY  which is derived by joining tables USER and POLICY.

Ideally , for a Normalized Schema  ,  2. is what should be followed  that is Application should DML USER and POLICY tables which are normalized (all normal forms should be conformed).

USER_POLICY is a denormalized dataset ideally suited for querying.
Any query should be off-loaded to a Read Replica so that the database that takes the DML workload does not have to take Read workload.

USER_POLICY should be a view on top of USER and POLICY tables obtained by joining USER and POLICY tables.